# Utility for displaying watermark on Windows screens

Tags: windows, digital-watermarking

I want to find utility capable of displaying image as transparent watermark on all screens connected to Windows machine. Basically I need it to work like watermark in Windows "pirate edition", staying on top of all open windows with transparency.

It would be nice for it to come with some sort of remote control. Preferably freeware.

If there is none I'll just write my own (I'll post it as answer then), but I am too lazy to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: OK, I'm curious as to what you want this for.

Comment: How are the screens connected to Windows?

Comment: @MichaelKohne practical joke idea made me interested in such software.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Standard physical screen, so it is just matter of enumerating screens for their HDC.